# Qt. Duda sobre pérdida de memoria en este programa con Valgrind

Tags: c++

Creo un código muy sencillo:

***Archivo miwidget.h***

```
#ifndef MIWIDGET_H
#define MIWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QCoreApplication>

class MiWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MiWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr);

private:
    QPushButton* boton;
};

#endif // MIWIDGET_H
```

***Archivo miwidget.cpp***

```
#include "miwidget.h"

MiWidget::MiWidget(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent)
{
    boton = new QPushButton("Salir",this);
    QObject::connect(boton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),qApp,SLOT(quit()));
}
```

***Archivo main.cpp***

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "miwidget.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MiWidget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Se supone que cuando el objeto `w` desaparezca al salir del programa, éste borrará al objeto `boton`, que es hijo suyo. Sin embargo cuando salgo del programa pulsando el botón, Valgrind me dice esto:

> ==5443== LEAK SUMMARY:
>
> ==5443==    definitely lost: 3,512 bytes in 12 blocks
>
> ==5443==    indirectly lost: 15,379 bytes in 647 blocks
>
> ==5443==      possibly lost: 3,884 bytes in 29 blocks
>
> ==5443==    still reachable: 1,749,125 bytes in 19,429 blocks
>
> ==5443==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
>
> ==5443==                         length64           : 7,552 bytes in 112 blocks
>
> ==5443==                         newarray           : 2,112 bytes in 52 blocks
>
> ==5443==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==5443==
>
> ==5443== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
>
> ==5443== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
>
> ==5443== ERROR SUMMARY: 49 errors from 49 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Comment: "*Se supone que cuando el objeto `w` desaparezca al salir del programa, éste borrará al objeto `boton`*" no veo por qué ¿dónde está el `delete boton`?

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus es una característica de Qt... los widgets anidados se destruyen cuando se borra el padre

Comment: @eferion Qt... promocionando malas prácticas en C++ desde 1992... ¬_¬

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus es tan mala práctica como usar `unique_ptr`... lo que te está dictando Qt es quien va a ser el resposanble de gestionar la vida de un objeto dado... y ese responsable es su padre. Interfaz clara y concisa... por supuesto puedes destruir manualmente el objeto en el destructor y no va a cambiar nada... al destruirse el botón se desvinculará del padre y el padre ya no intentará un segundo `delete`... a mí me parece un mecanismo bastante limpio máxime teniendo en cuenta la inmensa cantidad de widgets que pueden encontrarse en una ventana de usuario

Comment: He editado el código porque no había inicializado bien el constructor. No obstante me arroja todavía 45 errores (antes 50)

Comment: @eferion guardar en un puntero un objeto generado mediante `new` y después no hacer `delete` del mismo es una mala práctica, Qt la promociona porque oculta al programador su *magia* (usas un puntero, no una clase que envuelve el puntero) de manera que acostumbras al programador a no hacerse cargo de sus `new`. Así que, no le veo ni siquiera un parecido a punteros inteligentes, son punteros en crudo gestionados entre bambalinas... y no es la única queja que tengo de las malas prácticas de Qt ò_ó

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus piensa que cuando surgió Qt no existía ningún mecanismo tipo puntero inteligente que cumpliese unos mínimos exigibles para poder ser usado por Qt y tiraron por la vía que actualmente existe... cambiar su implementación interna en este aspecto tiraría por tierra millones de líneas de código de clientes de Qt y eso no creo que les abra muchas puertas... no estoy diciendo que sea la mejor solución sino que es una bastante limpia y que no evita que tu hagas la limpia manual...

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus ... por otro lado las ventanas las puedes diseñar con el editor de formularios y entonces no vas a tener ni un solo `new` en tu código, luego... sería ético obligarte a usar `delete` sobre objetos que tu no has creado? ¿te parece mejor práctica esa?

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus es por motivos como este que aún no se han puesto de acuerdo para añadir una librería de UI en el estándar de C++. Son temas espinosos y no hay una solución que contente a todo el mundo

Comment: Esta particularidad de Qt no la conocía, pero ahora que la conozco no me gusta, sigo opinando que incentiva malas prácticas; puede ser una excusa que no quieran actualizar su base de código, pero me parece una pobre excusa cuando hay actualizado sus librerías a las nuevas características del lenguaje. Y como he dicho antes: no es la única mala práctica que incentiva Qt; como herramienta es muy buena puede usarse adecuadamente, pero eso no quita que incentiva malas prácticas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un ejemplo tan sencillo podría dar para varias páginas:

1. Qt utiliza, como comentas, su propio mecanismo de gestión de memoria
2. Valgrind aunque es una magnífica herramienta no es infalible
3. Qt utiliza librerías de terceros... capas adicionales de código que pueden tener sus propias fugas de memoria.

Yo no me preocuparía por una posible fuga de memoria en la gestión del objeto `QPushButton` porque ese es uno de los pilares del desarrollo de Qt y está más que probado.

Por otro lado esta es una cuestión que ya ha surgido anteriormente en otros foros... como en el de [Qt](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/38925-Qt-example-with-memory-leak)

Lo que se recomienda en estos casos es configurar Valgrind para que omita ciertos errores característicos relacionados con Qt. Para más información revisa [este enlace](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Valgrind_Suppression_File_Howto)

Comment: Entonces la pregunta es, ¿es posible realmente discernir cuales son los errores debidos a mi código? Pregunto desde el desconocimiento, ya que apena he visto Valgrind. Me gustaría acotar por un lado los errores de la "lógica" de mi aplicación, y por otro, saber si he creado mal algún widget/dialogo que no esté referenciado a un padre y no pueda luego ser borrado convenientemente

Comment: Para reducir los *falsos positivos* provocados por Qt deberías seguir los pasos que se indican en el enlace con el que finaliza la respuesta.

Comment: Vale, gracias. Entonces me toca aprender más en profundidad Valgrind para ir puliendo la aplicación.